# how to configure my nginx conf for my own prerender server

Tags: nginx, prerender

I would like configure nginx to use my prerender server ( localhost:3005 ) launched with pm2
My website in on port localhost:3000

Actually I am using the service.prerender.io but it doesn't work with my local server..
it works in local but not with nginx
I tried the proxy pass: http://localhost:3005 and http://127.0.0.1:3005
but the error return me: 502 Bad Gateway

help !

```js
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.hidden.com;

    ssl on;
    # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.hidden.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.hidden.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';



location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token hiddentokenforstackoverflow;

    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|NinjaBot|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    if ($prerender = 1) {
        #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
        set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
        rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
        proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }

    # Proxy_pass configuration
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }

   
   


    
    
}
```

Can you tell me how to config my conf file

nginx return me this error:

```js
the error log return me this error:

2018/08/04 13:58:00 [error] 30272#30272: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.74.184.169, server: www.testeed.com, request: "GET /?_escaped_fragment_= HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3005/https://testeed.com/%3F_escaped_fragment_=", host: "testeed.com"
2018/08/04 13:58:00 [error] 30272#30272: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.74.184.169, server: www.testeed.com, request: "GET /?_escaped_fragment_= HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3005/https://testeed.com/%3F_escaped_fragment_=", host: "testeed.com"
```

Comment: Your nginx wont have a problem passing, it would be some other issue like host perhaps, can you paste us nginx error.log coresponding to this 502 response?

Comment: Also carefull with those if's, they were made for rewrite but in my experience will work good with set directives, i would test static request anyhow without ifs just in case as well

Comment: @DusanGligoric I put the error in the main post

Comment: @DusanGligoric Ok I found an error, The server.js doesn't want launch prerender, he returned multiple error like, 'let' unexpected
I don't know why..

Comment: Which version of NodeJS are you using? If you are seeing problems with "let", you might not be running a new enough version of NodeJS to support that.